# Why does not the picture in column A move with the sorting A to Z of column B?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets, first column is picture then B column is name. When I want to sort it A to Z, all the names get in alphabetical order, but the picture stays in the same position.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you added images using `Insert > Image...` in the menu. Such images are not associated with any particular cell, they are just placed at some fixed position within the spreadsheet. Think of them as existing in a different layer above the cells of the spreadsheets. (Inserted charts work the same way.)

You can put an image in a particular cell by using the [`IMAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447) command. For example, entering

```
=IMAGE("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-48.png")
```

in some cell puts the icon of Stack Overflow in that cell. If you have a column of icons and a column of site names, sorting the spreadsheet by names will rearrange the icons accordingly.

Note that to be added in this way, the image has to be accessible to the spreadsheet via a URL. If your images are locally stored, you can put them into Dropbox or Google Drive and use the URL generated by those services.

Answer (score 0):

As of at least April 2017 in my personal experience with Google Sheets if you add a row or column that affects an image in a Google Sheets cell it only APPEARS that the image has lost its connection to the cell placement. IF YOU PRESS F5 and REFRESH the sheet or close and RELOAD the sheet the image will appear in the proper place. It is a frustrating quirk of the program that until the sheet refreshes images suddenly appear to be all in the wrong place. Even if an image is larger than a single cell, it is ANCHORED by the upper left selector handle's location in a cell and will move with that cell. Confusingly if you think your images are in the wrong place before you refresh and move them to the place you want them and then refresh they will also just be in the correct position after the refresh so it is quite difficult to diagnose the problem or as others have done is just go back to using excel if they need image cell lock. Check it out, just refresh or reload or enter new data into the added row or column that affected your apparent image placement and you'll see them suddenly jump to their correct locations. Maddeningly quirky but not a problem at a basic level (Unless you want to SORT or Drag and Drop the columns or rows with the images... then the pictures end up in the wrong cells)